# How to convert a div in a HTML page into Image without using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

How can we convert a `div` element into an image without using canvas?

The browser that organization currently uses is IE8 and canvas is not compatible with it.

I'm looking for a solution using only JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: This is not possible (without emulating the entire DOM tree, creating a simulated draw surface using arrays, manually building, encoding the native image file and so forth).

Comment: doubt you can do it in IE8, get them to install chrome if they need modern feature sets

Comment: I agree with @KenFyrstenberg

Comment: Not Possible with Javascript/JQuery, but  you can have a look at **Phantomjs** , this might be useful for you http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can convert a div element into an image by using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image).

> dom-to-image is a library which can turn arbitrary DOM node into a vector (SVG) or raster (PNG or JPEG) image, written in JavaScript.

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node'); //assign our dom id to a variable
domtoimage.toPng(node)
.then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img); //append the converted image to html body
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
});
```

Here is the simple example of [converting html dom to image](https://plnkr.co/edit/f57wfo?p=preview)

Comment: This library is using the canvas element and svg foreignObject... which makes it unavailable for both any IE and latests Safari